# I used SvcUtil to create classes from WSDL. What do I deserialize into?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, deserialization, svcutil.exe

I used svcUtil.exe to create classes from https://gw.sam.gov/SAMWS/1.0/Entity?wsdl

but I cannot for the life of me find what to deserialize the result into? When I created my own classes the root is envelope but it isn't even in the new classes.

I can paste the classes but it is really long? Is there a general answer to this?

I will paste the classes upon request.

Thanks in advance...

The classes are over 10x too long to post.

Adding code for the pull:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; 



            var _url = "https://gw.sam.gov/SAMWS/1.0/Entity";

            //Run date is a specific date if provided otherwise use yesterday
            DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date;

            for (int hr = 0; hr < 24; hr++)
            {
                XMLclassRequest xmlSoap = new XMLclassRequest();
                string soap = xmlSoap.BuildSOAPrequest(startDateTime.AddHours(hr));
                //string soap2 = xmlSoap.BuildSOAPrequest2(startDateTime.AddHours(hr));

                string response = null;   //This is the original pull with FAR and DFAR Responses
                //string response2 = null;  //This is FAR and DFAR


                using (MyWebClient client = new MyWebClient())
                {
                    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
                    client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"http://tempuri.org/IMyService/MyOperation\"");
                    try
                    {
                        response = client.UploadString(_url, soap);
                        //response2 = client.UploadString(_url, soap2);
                    }
                    catch
                    { } //This will skip the hour attempted and move to next. The error I have been receiving is no data which is differently formatted XML that causes the error

                }

                //File.WriteAllText(@"D:\temp\bigpull.xml", response);

                MemoryStream stream = null;
                if (response != null)
                {

                    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(response);
                    stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
                }


                getEntities results;
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(getEntities));
                try
                { results = (getEntities)serializer.Deserialize(stream); }
                catch
                { } //This will skip the hour attempted and move to next. The error I have been receiving is no data which is differently formatted XML that causes the error
                stream.Close();

                string str;
            }
```

The response is coming back. I just can't get it into an object to use.

Comment: Well, normally it makes classes for the calls you need to make, and the datatypes you send/get back..

Comment: I've never used svcutil before. The request is to getEntities let me see if that exists

Comment: I am getting an error in my catch when tring to deserialize with error in xml document (1,2)

Comment: depending on what you do, you dont actually do the deserializeation its sent as xml but if you connected as a service to it, it handles that for you PS not played with that specific set but normally it returns an object which is the parsed xml

Comment: The problem with connecting as a service is I need to declare the SSL encryption in code using VS2012. If I could get around that I'd be happy as heck!

Comment: I thought you could.. must admit, not needed to myself

Comment: You have to create a Soap Header around the schema posted.  Most Customize schema are meant to be inserted in one of the standard General Schema

Comment: @jdweng I do not understand your comment. I've created SOAP in a separate class that works:  string soap = xmlSoap.BuildSOAPrequest(startDateTime.AddHours(hr));  If comment is about SOAP header in response, I am not sure what you mean

Comment: The Soap Header class should have an Property to your schema that you posted.  An actual XML will have both the Soap Header and the new classes for the shema you provided a like.  The General Soap Schema schema has a placeholder for Custom objects.

Comment: After filling a memory stream you have to set the position to zero before reading.  The memory stream position is at the end of the stream and you will get an error if you do not set position to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this loaded into an object but ended up loading it to an XDocument and parsed that:

```
    var _url = "https://gw.sam.gov/SAMWS/1.0/Entity";

    //Run date is a specific date if provided otherwise use yesterday
    DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date;

    for (int hr = 0; hr < 24; hr++)
    {
        XMLclassRequest xmlSoap = new XMLclassRequest();
        string soap = xmlSoap.BuildSOAPrequest(startDateTime.AddHours(hr));
        //string soap2 = xmlSoap.BuildSOAPrequest2(startDateTime.AddHours(hr));

        string response = null;   //This is the original pull with FAR and DFAR Responses
        //string response2 = null;  //This is FAR and DFAR


        using (MyWebClient client = new MyWebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
            client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"http://tempuri.org/IMyService/MyOperation\"");
            try
            {
                response = client.UploadString(_url, soap);
                //response2 = client.UploadString(_url, soap2);
            }
            catch
            { } //This will skip the hour attempted and move to next. The error I have been receiving is no data which is differently formatted XML that causes the error

        }

        //File.WriteAllText(@"D:\temp\far20190604.xml", response);

        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(response);

        var entities = from e in xdoc.Descendants("entity") select e;

        foreach (var e in entities)
        { 
            string DUNS = e.Descendants("DUNS").FirstOrDefault().Value;
            var provisions = from p in e.Descendants("provision") select p;

            foreach (var p in provisions)
            {
                string ParentID = p.Descendants("id").FirstOrDefault().Value;
                var answers = from a in p.Descendants("answer") select a;

                foreach (var a in answers)
                {
                    var section = a.Descendants("section").Count()>0?  a.Descendants("section").FirstOrDefault().Value : "";
                    var answerText = a.Descendants("answerText").Count() > 0 ? a.Descendants("answerText").FirstOrDefault().Value : "";

                    Console.WriteLine(DUNS + " " + ParentID + " " + section + " " + answerText);

                }
            }
        }
```